# Is there a C++11 normal sort algorithm?

Tags: sorting, c++11

At time (and some may argue more often than not) it's required to sort things the way a human would sort them (alphabetically, not ASCIIbetically), yet to my knowledge there is no convenient way to do so in C++ (I'm not even aware of a `boost` solution), and people have to roll their own. Has this been rectified in C++11 or later?

**Is there predicate or algorithm included in the c++ standard (from c++11 onwards) that allow sorting as humans would?**

That is, sorting `string`s like "z1, z2, z3" instead of "z1, z10, z100, z2, z20, z3" etc

**If not, is there some logical reason I've missed that they wouldn't include this functionality?**

Comment: I'd venture a guess that it's missing because it's not a sort that's globally defined; it's also performance-wise less efficient and I can imagine it also being locale-dependent.

Comment: You seem to be describing an algorithm that would break a string down into tokens (split at letter-digit boundary), then perform a comparison for strings of tokens. I don't think what you describe is in any way obvious (How does it handle symbols? Would "001" precede "01"?) I identify myself as a human, yet the description you gave seems very vague to me.

Comment: @DanielKO the above post is a sophisticated captcha.  As you failed the test, SO now knows you aren't human, but rather a bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer:**
No, there is nothing like that. There is one standard way for comparing strings [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp). `std::less` defaults to this too... and it's based on a [`lexicographical compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare). Also, by a "normal" sort I would understand [`std::sort (1)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), so this is it.

**A slight nitpick:** I don't think your concept is alphabetical sorting, it does not compare on the character level. "alphabetical" and not "ASCIIbetical" would be more like a different ordering of the letters.

Your concept is more like a alphanumerical, it needs to interpret string and treat a number as an atomic unit for comparison. This needs some parsing logic.

**An opinion:** I believe there is not a single thing that every human would do the same way. This might be a bit extreme, but even for the common sense example there would be ambiguity. Let's take your example and standard `sort` program included in most gnu systems. It has a switch `-h` for `human` and it does what you describe, however it also checks for the suffix of the number, so `2K` is smaller than `2G`. It is not obvious which option to choose. After this there would come a question what about fractional numbers? And so on.

To do this properly it would requite quite sophisticated architecture and logic and/or making non-obvious design choices.